# Yii framework: writing errors in apache log only

Tags: php, exception, yii

I'd like to write errors about r/w permissions of /protected/runtime directory into apache error log and do not throw any exception into interface. What i should do to resolve my 'problem'?

Thank you and sorry for my english!

---

the problem was resolved by using:

```
error_log($message);
```

and removing CException calls when script is trying to check runtime folder or run file_put_contents function

Answer (score 0):

When debug is off yii is displaying this error using (by default) site/error view, just change it to not display message text and display something generic (ex if code == 500 then display "Internal Error")

---

If you want to have error in apache log I see only a bit unclean way, anyway just tested and it works. Set `display_errors = Off` and `log_errors = On` in php.ini and then change action that handles errors from yii to restore default handlers and rise error again - it should result in log record in apache log and blank screen in browser, ex:

```
public function actionError() {
    if (($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)) {
        if (strpos($error['message'], 'runtime') !== false) {
            restore_error_handler();
            restore_exception_handler();
            user_error("Problem with runtime: " . $error['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
            exit();
        }
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
            echo $error['message'];
        } else {
            $this->render('error', $error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not a problem to show php errors in apache error.log, the problem is write an error when permissions to runtime directory are denied. This values already in my php.ini - no result. When i set chmod 0666 to runtime dir, i've got error in interface and nothing in apache error.log